# How to run ubuntu 14.04 from ram

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 from ram.  There are several articles that show how to do this with older ubuntu versions (using casper scripts and toram option), but none are applicable to 14.04. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I assume you are using a live USB to boot? And you'd like to copy the whole Ubuntu image to RAM before booting?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.